# How to extract values from (particular?) nested dictionary using spotify API?

Tags: python, spotify

I used the `sp.search(q, limit=1, offset=0, type='album', market=None)` function to search the information of an album in particular. I need now to extract some values from my output. Here's the code with my output:

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import json

credentials = json.load(open('autorizzazione.json'))
client_id = credentials['client_id']
client_secret = credentials['client_secret']
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=client_id,client_secret=client_secret)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

album_uri_research = sp.search("The Iron Giant", limit=1, offset=0, type='album', market=None)
album_uri_research
```

The output is the following:

```
{'albums': {'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=The+Iron+Giant&type=album&offset=0&limit=1',
  'items': [{'album_type': 'album',
   'artists': [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/68bqsIINo5RFICYwbkChbb'},
     'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/68bqsIINo5RFICYwbkChbb',
     'id': '68bqsIINo5RFICYwbkChbb',
     'name': 'Michael Kamen',
     'type': 'artist',
     'uri': 'spotify:artist:68bqsIINo5RFICYwbkChbb'}],
   'available_markets': ['AD',
    'AE',
    'AG',
    'AL',
    'AM',
    'AO',
    'AR',
    'AT',
    'AU',
    'AZ',
    'BA',
    'BB',
    'BD',
    'BE',
    'BF',
    'BG',
    'BH',
    'BI',
    'BJ',
    'BN',
    'BO',
    'BR',
    'BS',
    'BT',
    'BW',
    'BY',
    'BZ',
    'CA',
    'CD',
    'CG',
    'CH',
    'CI',
    'CL',
    'CM',
    'CO',
    'CR',
    'CV',
    'CW',
    'CY',
    'CZ',
    'DE',
    'DJ',
    'DK',
    'DM',
    'DO',
    'DZ',
    'EC',
    'EE',
    'EG',
    'ES',
    'ET',
    'FI',
    'FJ',
    'FM',
    'FR',
    'GA',
    'GB',
    'GD',
    'GE',
    'GH',
    'GM',
    'GN',
    'GQ',
    'GR',
    'GT',
    'GW',
    'GY',
    'HK',
    'HN',
    'HR',
    'HT',
    'HU',
    'ID',
    'IE',
    'IL',
    'IN',
    'IQ',
    'IS',
    'IT',
    'JM',
    'JO',
    'JP',
    'KE',
    'KG',
    'KH',
    'KI',
    'KM',
    'KN',
    'KR',
    'KW',
    'KZ',
    'LA',
    'LB',
    'LC',
    'LI',
    'LK',
    'LR',
    'LS',
    'LT',
    'LU',
    'LV',
    'LY',
    'MA',
    'MC',
    'MD',
    'ME',
    'MG',
    'MH',
    'MK',
    'ML',
    'MN',
    'MO',
    'MR',
    'MT',
    'MU',
    'MV',
    'MW',
    'MX',
    'MY',
    'MZ',
    'NA',
    'NE',
    'NG',
    'NI',
    'NL',
    'NO',
    'NP',
    'NR',
    'NZ',
    'OM',
    'PA',
    'PE',
    'PG',
    'PH',
    'PK',
    'PL',
    'PS',
    'PT',
    'PW',
    'PY',
    'QA',
    'RO',
    'RS',
    'RW',
    'SA',
    'SB',
    'SC',
    'SE',
    'SG',
    'SI',
    'SK',
    'SL',
    'SM',
    'SN',
    'SR',
    'ST',
    'SV',
    'SZ',
    'TD',
    'TG',
    'TH',
    'TJ',
    'TL',
    'TN',
    'TO',
    'TR',
    'TT',
    'TV',
    'TW',
    'TZ',
    'UA',
    'UG',
    'US',
    'UY',
    'UZ',
    'VC',
    'VE',
    'VN',
    'VU',
    'WS',
    'XK',
    'ZA',
    'ZM',
    'ZW'],
   'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/5ZeshDZM1ESVRgD1QLzDGg'},
   'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/5ZeshDZM1ESVRgD1QLzDGg',
   'id': '5ZeshDZM1ESVRgD1QLzDGg',
   'images': [{'height': 640,
     'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27389c97951e213a7383f7903cc',
     'width': 640},
    {'height': 300,
     'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e0289c97951e213a7383f7903cc',
     'width': 300},
    {'height': 64,
     'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000485189c97951e213a7383f7903cc',
     'width': 64}],
   'name': 'The Iron Giant (Original Score)',
   'release_date': '1999-01-01',
   'release_date_precision': 'day',
   'total_tracks': 23,
   'type': 'album',
   'uri': 'spotify:album:5ZeshDZM1ESVRgD1QLzDGg'}],
'limit': 1,
'next': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=The+Iron+Giant&type=album&offset=1&limit=1',
'offset': 0,
'previous': None,
'total': 28}}
```

I would like to extract the 'uri' of the album and the 'name' of the album. The top solution would be a data frame with a column called "Name of the album" and the value of the 'name' and another column called "uri of the album" and the value of the 'uri'.

Note that 'uri' is present both for the artist and the album. I need the album's one.

I've already tried everything I know, but no results.

Answer (score 0):

```
album_uri = album_uri_research["albums"]["items"][0]["uri"]
album_name = album_uri_research["albums"]["items"][0]["name"]
```

And you obtain:

```
'spotify:album:5ZeshDZM1ESVRgD1QLzDGg'
'The Iron Giant (Original Score)'
```

To create a data frame you could use a dictionary:

```
D = {}
D[album_name] = album_uri
data = {'Name of the album': D.keys(),
        'Album URI': D.values()} 
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
```